# How to setup an ip range for Docker containers?

Tags: docker, coreos

I am using CoreOS on my ESX (without cloud config - I have't any cloud provider).
I want to change the private ip for docker containers because they can't response to network that uses same ip range 172.x.x.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a network bridge, configure it with your ip range, add the bridge to the network interfaces and make Docker use it. For more info, read https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018720/how-to-change-docker0-setting-in-coreos